# How to handle return-by-value of objects with pointers correctly?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics, return-by-value

Suppose I have a class `Foo` which "has a" single member variable that is a pointer to some other object of `Bla`:

```
struct Foo {
    Bla *bla;

    Foo() {
        this->bla = new Bla();
    }
    ~Foo() {
        delete this->bla;
    }
};
```

How do I handle return-by-value of such objects?

```
Foo make_foo() {
    return Foo();
}
```

This creates a new `Foo` and `Bar`, returns a *copy* of the created `Foo` object including a copy of the internal pointer, and then destructs the local object and with it the `Bla` object. Thus, the following code fails:

```
Foo f = make_foo();
std::cout << f.bla << std::endl;
```

Is this generally considered poor design these days?

Should I  provide a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)? In that case, deep-copying more complex object trees can have severe performance impacts.

Should I provide a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)? Would that handle the `bla` pointer correctly?

Comment: Why do you think the code fails? `bla` is also copied (the pointer itself). You might want to see [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: If appropriate, there is also [copy-on-write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628938/what-is-copy-on-write) for your copy constructor, which may mitigate your performance impacts. Share some reference counted copies of `bla` (e.g. use a [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)), then don't make a deep copy until you actually need to modify the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your class allocates dynamic memory and deallocates the memory in the destructor, follow [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Provide a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

If you understand move semantics or intend to use rvalue references, provide a move constructor and move assignment operator as well. See [Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) for further details.